# sqlalchemy and asyncpg – set postgres statement_timeout

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.10, postgresql-13, asyncpg

When doing

```
engine: AsyncEngine = create_async_engine(...)
```

and then

```
async with engine.connect() as conn:
    result: Result = await conn.execute(text("""..."""))
```

I would like to specify a timeout. Ideally I'd be able to set [statement_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) just for this one query execution. I am also fine with sqlalchemy doing the timeout and cancelling the query execution, but I can't find a way to set either.

Answer (score 3):

```
create_async_engine(
            db_url, connect_args={"command_timeout": 28.0}
        )
```

use command_timeout in connect_args in seconds

Answer (score 3):

`command_timeout` is set only on application level. It means query will still be running in database after timeout error in your application. To set timeout on database level you should use `server_settings`:

```py
create_async_engine(
    db_url, connect_args={"server_settings": {"statement_timeout": "10000"}},
)
```